# How do I build FFMpeg with non-default libraries when using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, package-management

I am trying to build FFMpeg with libvpx so that I can encode a WebM video. How can I re-build FFMpeg with libvpx using Homebrew?

I tried encoding a video with FFMPEG and libvpx installed separately I get the error `Encoder (codec vp8) not found for output stream #0:0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out: There is a `re-install` command for Homebrew: 
`brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-libvpx`

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this the answer, but I ended up just uninstalling FFMPEG and re-installing using `brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx`